# Style / themes not working

Tags: android

whenever I try to apply a VERY simple style in eclipse I get errors:
the style is as below (filename styles.xml in res/layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="commonStyle">
       <item name="android:background">#EEEEEE</item>
     </style>
</resources>
```

Regardless of whether I try to apply this to a LinearLayout (using style="@style/commonStyle") or to an activity in my manifest file (using android:theme="@style/commonStyle") I ALWAYS get the error "No resource found that matches the given name...".
If I try to apply an Android theme to an activity (say Theme.Black) it works just fine.
If I remove any usage of my style, my R.java file is generated as normal with the following contents:

```
    public static final int styles=0x7f030002; (in the generated layout class)
```

I have NO idea what is going on. It seems that NOONE is having the same troubles as me (Ive spent about 4 hours searching using google, and came up with not even a remotely close answer).

Ive tried restarting eclipse, clean building etc. etc. and nothing works what so ever...
So what am I missing?

Comment: ROFL...okay thanks, Ill accept the answers in a bit (cant yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving your `styles.xml` file to `res/values`.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource.html

Answer (score 0):

Styles need to be stored in the res/values folder :)

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html (See Defining Styles)

> The name of the XML file is arbitrary,
>   but it must use the .xml extension and
>   be saved in the res/values/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used styles in my code yet, however generally you need to use 
    android:
Does it work when you use this?:

```
<style android:name="commonStyle">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please verify the you call the style in the correct manner :

for example this might compile but will not work :

```
style="mainButtonText"
```

this is the correct way to call style:

`style="@style/mainButtonText`"